# Desearilze JSON Java EE REST with Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a Java EE REST service, and have the following JSON that I am POSTing here:

```
[
  {"name":"identifier","value":"9d036307-efc1-4c84-a8fb-cf5b0bffca43"},
  {"name":"form.field.decision","value":"Approved"},
  {"name":"form.field.reason","value":"asdf"}
]
```

Here is the method, which works, but is ugly.

```
@POST
@Path("process-response")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, String> processResponse(String responseData) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> retval = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(Object o : om.readValue(responseData, java.util.ArrayList.class)){
        Map<String, String> m = (Map) o;
        retval.put(m.get("name"), m.get("value"));
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Is there some way that I can write a class or something that gets annotated onto the method here to indicate I want to use it?

Something like:

```
public class StringToMapCustom() implmeents ???? {
  ...
}
```

Then, to the working method above, I would do something like:

```
@DecodeWith(StringToMapCustom.class)
@POST
...
```

Any ideas?  I cannot find any docs like this.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to just create a a POJO, say `KeyValue`, with a `name` and `value` property, and just deserialize to `List<KeyValue>`

Comment: So what about when I want to find a value?  Instead of a hashtable lookup I have to traverse a list and check each key to get the value?  I was looking for something a little better than that, honestly.